# POST запрос к VK API для изменения виджета сообщества

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, post, request

Нужен рабочий пример тела запроса - как используя Node.js с npm 'request' сделать POST запрос к методу [appWidgets.update](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests) . group_id куда вставлять? access_token ключ обязательно вручную только [из группы брать](http://prntscr.com/n931wr)? Придется ли делать input-text внутри приложения чтобы его администратор там вручную сохранял каждый раз? Можно ли с сервера вызывать VK.callMethod("showGroupSettingsBox", 64) чтобы получить сразу с него ключ?
Примерный код:

```
const request = require('request')
const code = 'return { \
            "title": "My Table", \
            "title_url": "https://vk.com/public123", \
            "title_counter": 31, \
            "more": "Посмотреть все результаты", \
            "more_url": "https://vk.com/app123_-777", \
            "head": [{ \


        "text": "Название первой колонки" \
                }, { \
                    "text": "Название второй колонки", \
                    "align": "center" \
                }], \
         ...'

request.post({
    url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.update',
    form: {
       'type': 'table',
       'access_token': access_token,
       'code': code,
       'v':'5.92'
    },
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  },(error, res, body) => {
        if (error) console.error(error)
        console.log(res.statusCode,body)
  })
```

Comment: Проверил: приведенный код рабочий и изменения в виджет вносятся, но как автоматизировать получение access_token пока неясно. Делать для ключа поле с привязкой к group_id скорее всего неверно.

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_group?f=5.%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20access_token нужно выполнить запрос к oauth.vk.com для получения access_token

Comment: решили проблему?
У меня проблема в том что выдает ошибку `vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: app must be installed in group as community app`

Comment: Да решил, токен с фронта можно брать из "VKWebAppGetCommunityToken", передавать на бэк, сохранять, отправлять запрос как форму `postBody := url.Values{
  "type":         {"table"},
  "access_token": {SettingWidgetToken},
  "code":         {widgetCode},
  "v":            {"5.92"},
 }
 resp, err := http.PostForm("https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.update", postBody)`